# Simple Python Regex Matching

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a string with a regular expression and only one of the two cases are working

**String**

```
ABCD 123 - Abcdef 0000
ABCD 123/DEFG123 - Abcdef 0000
```

**RegEx**

```
[A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}
```

This matches the 1st one and Im trying to match it to both and this is the new expression I tried

```
[A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9\\/]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}
```

This matches `DEFG123 - Abcdef 0000` out of the entire `ABCD 123/DEFG123 - Abcdef 0000` but I am trying to get the entire string out of this. This is the code I'm using

```
regex = re.compile(expression)
r = regex.search(string)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to be escaping the `/` ?

Comment: I tried your second expression and it worked fine.  One difference might be that I used r"[A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9\\/]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}
", which means you don't have to escape "\" in the python string.  Note the 'r' before the string, so r"expression"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape is what's wrong. Taken out:

```
string_one = 'ABCD 123 - Abcdef 0000'
string_two = 'ABCD 123/DEFG123 - Abcdef 0000'
pattern = r'[A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9/]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
if regex.search(string_one):
    print "string one matches!"
if regex.search(string_two):
    print "string two matches!"

# output:
string one matches!
string two matches!
```

Note that my use of a raw string ( `r'this is a raw string'` ) is unnecessarily, but I obsessively use raw strings for patterns because they prevent most backslash interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to escape your forward slash.  Remove the double `\` and you should be set.  Use regexpal.com to test this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra backslash:

```
[A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9\/]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}
```

Or you could use grouping:

```
([A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4})|([A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9\\/]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4})
```

This combines both of the RegExes from above and matches both lines.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code:

```
import re
def foo(s):
    r = re.compile('[A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9\\/]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}')
    m = r.search(s)
    return s[m.start():m.end()]
print foo('ABCD 123 - Abcdef 0000')
print foo('ABCD 123/DEFG123 - Abcdef 0000')
```

and got the following result:

```
ABCD 123 - Abcdef 0000
ABCD 123/DEFG123 - Abcdef 0000
```

Try to use `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) chars:

```
r = re.compile('^[A-Z]+ [A-Z0-9\\/]{2,20} - [A-Z][a-z]+ [0-9]{4}$')
```